# Elegant way to check for missing packages and install them?

Tags: r, package, r-faq

I seem to be sharing a lot of code with coauthors these days. Many of them are novice/intermediate R users and don't realize that they have to install packages they don't already have.

Is there an elegant way to call `installed.packages()`, compare that to the ones I am loading and install if missing?

Comment: @krlmlr What about the accepted answer is out of date and requires revision? It works for me (for a few quick tests) under `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`.

Comment: @BrianDiggs: At least three packages have appeared that address this problem, only one is referenced below. Is there even more -- that's the question.

Comment: @krlmlr There seems to be a bit of an ironic chicken-and-egg problem about using a package to ensure (others) have necessary packages. But certainly worth having someone who knows about them write up an answer.

Comment: @BrianDiggs: Bootstrapping this installation-checking package is a necessary nuisance, but a small one. Unless, of course, the functionality finds its way into `base`... ;-)

Comment: Coming from Node.js, it is insane how hard this is. How is this not a first class function of the language?

Answer (score 406, accepted):

Yes.  If you have your list of packages, compare it to the output from `installed.packages()[,"Package"]` and install the missing packages.  Something like this:

```
list.of.packages <- c("ggplot2", "Rcpp")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
```

Otherwise:

If you put your code in a package and make them dependencies, then they will automatically be installed when you install your package.

Comment: I think the proper syntax is: 
`if(length(new.packages)>0) {install.packages(new.packages)}`

Comment: @psql , Shine is right, since ">0" is "implicit" within the if condition. 
run this for to verify it:
`new.packages <- c(1,2)`
`length(new.packages)`
`if(length(new.packages)){print("hello!")}else{print("oh no!")}`

Comment: The doc of installed.packages states: "This can be slow when thousands of packages are installed, so do not use this to find out if a named package is installed (use system.file or find.package)..."

Comment: Agree with Thomas, this would be better performance with `require` instead of checking `installed.packages`

Comment: `packrat` was made for this. It is a reproducible package management system. This way is going about it the wrong way and messes with someone else's environment and not reproducible. Packrat has it own folder and environment for the shared libraries. https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/

Comment: `packrat` is going to be one big mess if you have many packages in your project though.

Comment: Can't say this is elegant. can cause RStudio to crash if the library list is big.

Comment: i've added this to the top of my source and i get the error, "could not find function "installed.packages" "  Does anyone have leads on this?

Comment: if the list.of.packages contains packages from both CRAN and Bioconductor, how to work with it? thanks a lot! @shane

Comment: I have created a loop based on this answer, I hope it helps: `if(length(new.packages) > 0) {install.packages(new.packages, dependencies = TRUE) print(paste0("The following package was installed:", new.packages)) } else if (length(new.packages) == 0) {print("All packages were already installed previously")}`

Comment: Just upgraded ```R``` to version 4.1.2 and ```RStudio``` to to 2021.09.1 Build 372 on macOS 10.15.7 and although the packages I need are indeed not installed, variable ```new.packages``` throws ```character(0)```. I tried to update manually all the packages, to no avail. Any ideas on what changed and what to do?

Answer (score 320):

Dason K. and I have the **pacman** package that can do this nicely.  The function `p_load` in the package does this.  The first line is just to ensure that pacman is installed.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(package1, package2, package_n)
```

Comment: What's the status of the package? I can't see in on C-RAN.

Comment: @Dason and I have been pretty busy with dissertation writing.  We have decided to release on Feb 14th to CRAN.

Comment: @MERose **pacman** is now on CRAN http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pacman/index.html

Comment: Have installed now and works wonderfully; should be part of base!

Comment: The only way this would be better would be if it checked for `/` and, if found, install/load from github automatically.

Comment: @Tyler Does it handle dependancies ? I couldn't see a `dep=TRUE` option

Comment: @DanChaltiel for me, pacman installs dependencies by default.  Not sure if there's a way to tell it don't do that.

Comment: @DanChaltiel why would you not want the dependencies?  The package likely won't work without them?

Comment: Of course I want them. On the contrary it happened that I often had to install some dependencies manually, so maybe `pacman` was at fault. It seems I'm the only one in this case.

Comment: I swear I search this answer on a monthly basis because I forget the exact syntax of this. Cheers for this one.

Comment: @NealBarsch if you mean the `if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")` there's a function in pacman called `p_boot()` that maks this line for you automagically and copies it to the clipboard.

Comment: Is there a way that I can define the version of the package?

Comment: @airstrike: recognizing the / for github packages is done by librarian, which is one reason I prefer it (see my answer)

Comment: @JohannesTitz that looks about 100x better. thanks for the note

Comment: As I mentioned under the post that recommended `packrat`, `renv` is now probably the more widely used and preferred reproducible environment solution.  It has several additional benefits over and above both `pacman` and `packrat,` that I detailed in my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77036762/4615298.

Answer (score 98):

You can just use the return value of `require`:

```
if(!require(somepackage)){
    install.packages("somepackage")
    library(somepackage)
}
```

I use `library` after the install because it will throw an exception if the install wasn't successful or the package  can't be loaded for some other reason. You make this more robust and reuseable:

```
dynamic_require <- function(package){
  if(eval(parse(text=paste("require(",package,")")))) return(TRUE)
  
  install.packages(package)
  return(eval(parse(text=paste("require(",package,")"))))
}
```

The downside to this method is that you have to pass the package name in quotes, which you don't do for the real `require`.

Comment: You can simplify your life a lot by using `character.only = TRUE` in `require`, but then I guess there is nothing to differentiate your answer from mine.

Comment: This looks nice but it doesn't seem to work, at least for me. When I tried the robust version of this, I get two error messages as R doesn't know how to handle "return True" and "return eval" for some reason. So I would really like a function like this that loads a package if present in my library and otherwise installs (and afterwards loads) the package. Ideally I would then use this as a default to load packages. At least it seems it would make sense to do so and would save some time.

Answer (score 53):

A lot of the answers above (and on duplicates of this question) rely on `installed.packages` which is bad form. From the documentation:

> This can be slow when thousands of packages are installed, so do not use this to find out if a named package is installed (use system.file or find.package) nor to find out if a package is usable (call require and check the return value) nor to find details of a small number of packages (use packageDescription). It needs to read several files per installed package, which will be slow on Windows and on some network-mounted file systems.

So, a better approach is to attempt to load the package using `require` and and install if loading fails (`require` will return `FALSE` if it isn't found). I prefer this implementation:

```
using<-function(...) {
    libs<-unlist(list(...))
    req<-unlist(lapply(libs,require,character.only=TRUE))
    need<-libs[req==FALSE]
    if(length(need)>0){ 
        install.packages(need)
        lapply(need,require,character.only=TRUE)
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
using("RCurl","ggplot2","jsonlite","magrittr")
```

This way it loads all the packages, then goes back and installs all the missing packages (which if you want, is a handy place to insert a prompt to ask if the user wants to install packages). Instead of calling `install.packages` separately for each package it passes the whole vector of uninstalled packages just once.

Here's the same function but with a windows dialog that asks if the user wants to install the missing packages

```
using<-function(...) {
    libs<-unlist(list(...))
    req<-unlist(lapply(libs,require,character.only=TRUE))
    need<-libs[req==FALSE]
    n<-length(need)
    if(n>0){
        libsmsg<-if(n>2) paste(paste(need[1:(n-1)],collapse=", "),",",sep="") else need[1]
        print(libsmsg)
        if(n>1){
            libsmsg<-paste(libsmsg," and ", need[n],sep="")
        }
        libsmsg<-paste("The following packages could not be found: ",libsmsg,"\n\r\n\rInstall missing packages?",collapse="")
        if(winDialog(type = c("yesno"), libsmsg)=="YES"){       
            install.packages(need)
            lapply(need,require,character.only=TRUE)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty elegant way, much better than the accepted one. I'll include it in my personal library. Thanks.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. One thing though: `winDialog()` is platform specific and limited to Windows only.

Answer (score 40):

```
if (!require('ggplot2')) install.packages('ggplot2'); library('ggplot2')
```

"ggplot2" is the package. It checks to see if the package is installed, if it is not it installs it. It then loads the package regardless of which branch it took.

Answer (score 36):

TL;DR you can use `find.package()` for this.

Almost all the answers here rely on either (1) `require()` or (2) `installed.packages()` to check if a given package is already installed or not.

I'm adding an answer because these are unsatisfactory for a lightweight approach to answering this question.

- `require` has the side effect of loading the package's namespace, which may not always be desirable
- `installed.packages` is a bazooka to light a candle -- it will check *the universe* of installed packages first, then we check if our one (or few) package(s) are "in stock" at this library. No need to build a haystack just to find a needle.

This answer was also inspired by [@ArtemKlevtsov's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082613/3576984) in a similar spirit on a duplicated version of this question. He noted that `system.file(package=x)` can have the desired affect of returning `''` if the package isn't installed, and something with `nchar > 1` otherwise.

If we look under the hood of how `system.file` accomplishes this, we can see it uses a different `base` function, `find.package`, which we could use directly:

```
# a package that exists
find.package('data.table', quiet=TRUE)
# [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/data.table"

# a package that does not
find.package('InstantaneousWorldPeace', quiet=TRUE)
# character(0)
```

We can also look under the hood at `find.package` to see how it works, but this is mainly an instructive exercise -- the only ways to slim down the function that I see would be to skip some robustness checks. But the basic idea is: look in `.libPaths()` -- any installed package `pkg` will have a `DESCRIPTION` file at `file.path(.libPaths(), pkg)`, so a quick-and-dirty check is `file.exists(file.path(.libPaths(), pkg, 'DESCRIPTION')`.

Comment: Well researched answer! Nevertheless I was a bit puzzled by the ambiguous return: `file.exists(file.path(.libPaths(), 'sf', 'DESCRIPTION'))
[1]  TRUE FALSE`. Should I just go with the first bool when designing a package installation chain?

Comment: @saQuist yes, IINM that's what install.packages does. actually it's probably more like a for loop, looping over the .libPaths() and exiting once success

Comment: nchar() here throws an "argument is of length zero" error when I wrap find.package(my_package_name, quiet = TRUE) into a function.

Answer (score 24):

This solution will take a character vector of package names and attempt to load them, or install them if loading fails. It relies on the return behaviour of `require` to do this because...

> **`require`** returns (invisibly) a logical indicating whether the required package is available

Therefore we can simply see if we were able to load the required package and if not, install it with dependencies. So given a character vector of packages you wish to load...

```
foo <- function(x){
  for( i in x ){
    #  require returns TRUE invisibly if it was able to load package
    if( ! require( i , character.only = TRUE ) ){
      #  If package was not able to be loaded then re-install
      install.packages( i , dependencies = TRUE )
      #  Load package after installing
      require( i , character.only = TRUE )
    }
  }
}

#  Then try/install packages...
foo( c("ggplot2" , "reshape2" , "data.table" ) )
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to call `require` again after installing?

Comment: @krlmlr Nope, because in order for the `if` statement to be evaluated it must first evaluate `require`, the side-effect of which is loading the package if it is available!

Comment: SimonO101: I think krlmlr means in the if statement, after the call to `install.packages`, as this wouldn't actually load that package.  But (to @krlmlr) I suspect the intent is that this code fragment would only be called once; you wouldn't write this every time you required the package.  Instead you'd run it once ahead of time and then call `require` as usual as needed.

Comment: @Aaron ah yes ok, I see what you mean, and yes your interpretation is correct. I'll edit it slightly to be more explicit about loading after installing.

Comment: Is it possible that the definition of you own `R` function doesn't work when you run the script from the `shell`?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to make the second `require` a call to `library` so that it fails noisily if it is still unable to attach the package for some reason?

Answer (score 16):

Although the answer of Shane is really good, for one of my project I needed to remove the ouput messages, warnings and install packages *automagically*. I have finally managed to get this script:

```
InstalledPackage <- function(package) 
{
    available <- suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(sapply(package, require, quietly = TRUE, character.only = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)))
    missing <- package[!available]
    if (length(missing) > 0) return(FALSE)
    return(TRUE)
}

CRANChoosen <- function()
{
    return(getOption("repos")["CRAN"] != "@CRAN@")
}

UsePackage <- function(package, defaultCRANmirror = "http://cran.at.r-project.org") 
{
    if(!InstalledPackage(package))
    {
        if(!CRANChoosen())
        {       
            chooseCRANmirror()
            if(!CRANChoosen())
            {
                options(repos = c(CRAN = defaultCRANmirror))
            }
        }

        suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(install.packages(package)))
        if(!InstalledPackage(package)) return(FALSE)
    }
    return(TRUE)
}
```

Use:

```
libraries <- c("ReadImages", "ggplot2")
for(library in libraries) 
{ 
    if(!UsePackage(library))
    {
        stop("Error!", library)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
# List of packages for session
.packages = c("ggplot2", "plyr", "rms")

# Install CRAN packages (if not already installed)
.inst <- .packages %in% installed.packages()
if(length(.packages[!.inst]) > 0) install.packages(.packages[!.inst])

# Load packages into session 
lapply(.packages, require, character.only=TRUE)
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my option. It allows for multiple packages to be installed, but only installs those that are not already installed.

Answer (score 8):

Use `packrat` so that the shared libraries are exactly the same and not changing other's environment.

In terms of elegance and best practice I think you're fundamentally going about it the wrong way. The package `packrat` was designed for these issues. It is developed by RStudio by Hadley Wickham. Instead of them having to install dependencies and possibly mess up someone's environment system, `packrat` uses its own directory and installs all the dependencies for your programs in there and doesn't touch someone's environment.

> Packrat is a dependency management system for R.
>
> R package dependencies can be frustrating. Have you ever had to use trial-and-error to figure out what R packages you need to install to make someone else’s code work–and then been left with those packages globally installed forever, because now you’re not sure whether you need them? Have you ever updated a package to get code in one of your projects to work, only to find that the updated package makes code in another project stop working?
>
> We built packrat to solve these problems. Use packrat to make your R projects more:
>
> - Isolated: Installing a new or updated package for one project won’t break your other projects, and vice versa. That’s because packrat gives each project its own private package library.
> - Portable: Easily transport your projects from one computer to another, even across different platforms. Packrat makes it easy to install the packages your project depends on.
> - Reproducible: Packrat records the exact package versions you depend on, and ensures those exact versions are the ones that get installed wherever you go.

https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/

Comment: I realize you posted this answer in 2017, before the advent of `renv`, but in case others come across this answer, I figured they'd benefit from this note.  The preferred and more modern package that handles all of this better, in my opinion, is `renv`.  I added details about `renv` here, with some links to the documentation that describes why this is a better package solution.  In fact, `renv` has replaced `packrat` as the Reproducible Environment solution within R Studio's user interface when creating new R Studio Projects.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77036762/4615298

Answer (score 7):

This is the purpose of the [rbundler package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbundler/index.html): to provide a way to control the packages that are installed for a specific project. Right now the package works with the devtools functionality to install packages to your project's directory. The functionality is similar to Ruby's [bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

If your project is a package (recommended) then all you have to do is load rbundler and bundle the packages. The `bundle` function will look at your package's `DESCRIPTION` file to determine which packages to bundle.

```
library(rbundler)
bundle('.', repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Now the packages will be installed in the .Rbundle directory.

If your project isn't a package, then you can fake it by creating a `DESCRIPTION` file in your project's root directory with a Depends field that lists the packages that you want installed (with optional version information):

```
Depends: ggplot2 (>= 0.9.2), arm, glmnet
```

Here's the github repo for the project if you're interested in contributing: [rbundler](https://github.com/opower/rbundler).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use the `setdiff` function to get the packages that aren't installed and then install them. In the sample below, we check if the **`ggplot2`** and **`Rcpp`** packages are installed before installing them.

```
unavailable <- setdiff(c("ggplot2", "Rcpp"), rownames(installed.packages()))
install.packages(unavailable)
```

In one line, the above can be written as:

```
install.packages(setdiff(c("ggplot2", "Rcpp"), rownames(installed.packages())))
```

Comment: I use the same approach. We can also use `installed.packages()[,'Package']` instead of `rownames(installed.packages())`.

Answer (score 7):

The current version of RStudio (>=1.2) includes a feature to detect missing packages in `library()` and `require()` calls, and prompts the user to install them:

> Detect missing R packages
>
> Many R scripts open with calls to `library()` and `require()` to load the packages they need in order to execute. If you open an R script that references packages that you don’t have installed, RStudio will now offer to install all the needed packages in a single click. No more typing `install.packages()` repeatedly until the errors go away!
> https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/11/19/rstudio-1-2-preview-the-little-things/

This seems to address the original concern of OP particularly well:

> Many of them are novice/intermediate R users and don't realize that they have to install packages they don't already have.

Answer (score 6):

Sure.

You need to compare 'installed packages' with 'desired packages'. That's very close to what I do with [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries) as I need to compare 'stored known packages' with 'currently known packages' to determine new and/or updated packages.

So do something like

```
AP <- available.packages(contrib.url(repos[i,"url"]))   # available t repos[i]
```

to get all known packages, simular call for currently installed packages and compare that to a given set of target packages.

Answer (score 5):

The following simple function works like a charm:

```
  usePackage<-function(p){
      # load a package if installed, else load after installation.
      # Args:
      #   p: package name in quotes

      if (!is.element(p, installed.packages()[,1])){
        print(paste('Package:',p,'Not found, Installing Now...'))
        install.packages(p, dep = TRUE)}
      print(paste('Loading Package :',p))
      require(p, character.only = TRUE)  
    }
```

(not mine, found this on the web some time back and had been using it since then. not sure of the original source)

Answer (score 5):

I use following function to install package if `require("<package>")` exits with package not found error. It will query both - CRAN and Bioconductor repositories for missing package.

Adapted from the original work by Joshua Wiley, 
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Install-package-automatically-if-not-there-td2267532.html

```r
install.packages.auto <- function(x) { 
  x <- as.character(substitute(x)) 
  if(isTRUE(x %in% .packages(all.available=TRUE))) { 
    eval(parse(text = sprintf("require(\"%s\")", x)))
  } else { 
    #update.packages(ask= FALSE) #update installed packages.
    eval(parse(text = sprintf("install.packages(\"%s\", dependencies = TRUE)", x)))
  }
  if(isTRUE(x %in% .packages(all.available=TRUE))) { 
    eval(parse(text = sprintf("require(\"%s\")", x)))
  } else {
    source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    #biocLite(character(), ask=FALSE) #update installed packages.
    eval(parse(text = sprintf("biocLite(\"%s\")", x)))
    eval(parse(text = sprintf("require(\"%s\")", x)))
  }
}
```

Example:

```
install.packages.auto(qvalue) # from bioconductor
install.packages.auto(rNMF) # from CRAN
```

PS: `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` & `biocLite(character(), ask=FALSE)` will update all installed packages on the system. This can take a long time and consider it as a full R upgrade which may not be warranted all the time!

Comment: It could be improved by checking if packages are actually avilable on cran or bc. Also it should use library at the end to throw an error if the installation failed or a package does not exist. See my improved version called `loadpack()` on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holgerbrandl/datautils/master/R/core_commons.R

Answer (score 5):

Today, I stumbled on two handy function provided by the rlang package, namely, `is_installed()` and `check_installed()`.

From the [help page](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/is_installed.html) (emphasis added):

> These functions check that packages are installed with minimal side effects. If installed, the packages will be loaded but not attached.
>
> `is_installed()` doesn't interact with the user. It simply returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether the packages are installed.
>
> In **interactive sessions**, `check_installed()` **asks the user whether to install missing packages**. If the user accepts, the packages are installed [...]. If the session is non interactive or if the user chooses not to install the packages, the current evaluation is aborted.

```r
interactive()
#> [1] FALSE
rlang::is_installed(c("dplyr"))
#> [1] TRUE
rlang::is_installed(c("foobarbaz"))
#> [1] FALSE
rlang::check_installed(c("dplyr"))
rlang::check_installed(c("foobarbaz"))
#> Error:
#> ! The package `foobarbaz` is required.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Thought I'd contribute the one I use:

```
testin <- function(package){if (!package %in% installed.packages())    
install.packages(package)}
testin("packagename")
```

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented the function to install and load required R packages silently. Hope might help. Here is the code:

```
# Function to Install and Load R Packages
Install_And_Load <- function(Required_Packages)
{
    Remaining_Packages <- Required_Packages[!(Required_Packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])];

    if(length(Remaining_Packages)) 
    {
        install.packages(Remaining_Packages);
    }
    for(package_name in Required_Packages)
    {
        library(package_name,character.only=TRUE,quietly=TRUE);
    }
}

# Specify the list of required packages to be installed and load    
Required_Packages=c("ggplot2", "Rcpp");

# Call the Function
Install_And_Load(Required_Packages);
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite basic one.

```
pkgs = c("pacman","data.table")
if(length(new.pkgs <- setdiff(pkgs, rownames(installed.packages())))) install.packages(new.pkgs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your main objective " to install libraries they don't already have. " and regardless of using " instllaed.packages() ". The following function mask the original function of require. It tries to load and check the named package "x" , if it's not installed, install it directly including dependencies; and lastly load it normaly. you rename the function name from 'require' to 'library' to maintain integrity . The only limitation is packages names should be quoted.

```
require <- function(x) { 
  if (!base::require(x, character.only = TRUE)) {
  install.packages(x, dep = TRUE) ; 
  base::require(x, character.only = TRUE)
  } 
}
```

So you can load and installed package the old fashion way of R. 
    require ("ggplot2")
    require  ("Rcpp")

Comment: If you don't like your answer anymore, don't vandalize it - just delete it.

Comment: Well, I tried , but i couldn't. I think my NoScript extension of FF is disabling it or I don't have the rights and credits to delete my own answer. LoL
However, I think Livius is quite near to my answer, thought without masking. 
Thanks Michael Petrotta. for the notification.

Comment: You should see a `delete` link above these comments. If you don't, and you still want to delete, use the `flag` link, select "other", and explain to a moderator that you'd like the answer removed.

Answer (score 2):

```
 48 lapply_install_and_load <- function (package1, ...)
 49 {
 50     #
 51     # convert arguments to vector
 52     #
 53     packages <- c(package1, ...)
 54     #
 55     # check if loaded and installed
 56     #
 57     loaded        <- packages %in% (.packages())
 58     names(loaded) <- packages
 59     #
 60     installed        <- packages %in% rownames(installed.packages())
 61     names(installed) <- packages
 62     #
 63     # start loop to determine if each package is installed
 64     #
 65     load_it <- function (p, loaded, installed)
 66     {
 67         if (loaded[p])
 68         {
 69             print(paste(p, "loaded"))
 70         }
 71         else
 72         {
 73             print(paste(p, "not loaded"))
 74             if (installed[p])
 75             {
 76                 print(paste(p, "installed"))
 77                 do.call("library", list(p))
 78             }
 79             else
 80             {
 81                 print(paste(p, "not installed"))
 82                 install.packages(p)
 83                 do.call("library", list(p))
 84             }
 85         }
 86     }
 87     #
 88     lapply(packages, load_it, loaded, installed)
 89 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
if (!require("ggsci")) biocLite("ggsci")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using lapply family and anonymous function approach you may:

1. Try to attach all listed packages.
2. Install missing only (using `||` lazy evaluation).
3. Attempt to attach again those were missing in step 1 and installed in step 2.
4. Print each package final load status (`TRUE` / `FALSE`).

   ```
   req <- substitute(require(x, character.only = TRUE))
   lbs <- c("plyr", "psych", "tm")
   sapply(lbs, function(x) eval(req) || {install.packages(x); eval(req)})

   plyr psych    tm 
   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an older question, but much of the technology in R has been greatly improved in recent months and years to address this exact issue.  The generally accepted and modern approach for handling the sharing of code with package dependencies that may or may not be installed on a collaborator's computer or the target computer is to use the [`renv` package](https://github.com/rstudio/renv) ("`renv`" is short for "Reproducible Environment") which was first made available as `renv` [`0.8.0`](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/news/index.html#renv-083) in late October of 2019.  Version `1.0.0` was officially released on July 7, 2023, and, as of this post, the current CRAN release is Version `1.0.2`, which was [made available](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/releases/tag/v1.0.2) last month on August 15, 2023.

This package greatly aids R collaborators in sharing code, packages (their exact version and their dependencies and *their* versions), and even the tracking of the exact version of R that was used to build and execute code in an R project.

To use it, typically the initial programmer creates an R project in R Studio/Posit and then initializes `renv` within the project using the command `renv::init()`. When this is executed, R does the following:

1. Creates an ***project specific*** package library within the project, rather than using the ***general/global library*** or libraries (e.g., `.libPaths()`).  As part of this step, `renv` also creates an `renv` directory which contains some settings and files that most users don't generally bother with as `renv` takes care of this for you.
2. Creates an .`Rprofile` file, which is a ***project-specific*** R project profile that configures R to use the project specific library created in step 1 when you open the project.
3. Creates a lockfile, called `renv.lock` in the project home directory, which logs details about all the packages and versions used by the project -- this is what makes using `renv` the most attractive option for sharing code with package and package/version dependencies.

After initializing the project environment with the `init()` command, the initial programmer develops and writes code as typical, installing packages in the usual manner (e.g., by simply entering `install.packages("PackageName")` into the console) along they way as they are needed.  These packages are stored into the project library, however, rather than any global library.  When the initial programmer feels the code is in a satisfactory state to share the entire project, he simply issues the `renv::snapshot()` command which simply updates the lockfile created in step 3 above, with the names, version numbers, etc. of all the packages used in the project.

At this point the initial programmer can share the project with other collaborators (ideally this is done through [GitHub](https://github.com/), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/devops), etc.).  When any new collaborators open the R project, they simply enter the command `renv::restore()` at the console.  This will install the exact same version of every package used in the project (and it will be restored into the ***project library*** rather than the user's global package library).

This is an excellent workflow because it will ensure all users are working with the same version of the packages the initial developer used.  Without `renv`, it's possible that a collaborator has a totally different version of an R package installed in their global library, and it may function differently from the initial developer's package.  This could result in the code breaking, or worse yet, running, but resulting in different output, possibly unbeknownst to the end users.

As perfectly described on the [*Introduction to renv*](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html) vignette, `renv` benefits users by ensuring package **isolation**, **reproducibility** across users and environments, and **portability**.  `renv()` also enjoys some other benefits like **caching** of R packages so that they don't have to be downloaded multiple times when used across projects.  [It also works with Python](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/python.html) and [Python packages](https://pypi.org/).  If you also want to ensure that every detail of an enviroment—including the operating system and other external (to R/R Studio) dependencies—are in place, you can easily do so too by combining `renv` with a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) image [to fully containerize a solution](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/docker.html)!

One final note:  if `renv` seems similar to `packrat`, that's because it is, somewhat.  In fact the deverlopers of `rev` first attempted to build a reproducible environment package using `packrat` but gave up and "rolled their own" after struggling with its limitations.  But it's vastly better too, I'd argue.  The good news is, if you're already using `packrat` and want to upgrade to this modern tool, you can easily do so with the `renv::migrate()` command!

Good luck and happy collaborating!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following which will check if package is installed and if dependencies are updated, then loads the package.

```
p<-c('ggplot2','Rcpp')
install_package<-function(pack)
{if(!(pack %in% row.names(installed.packages())))
{
  update.packages(ask=F)
  install.packages(pack,dependencies=T)
}
 require(pack,character.only=TRUE)
}
for(pack in p) {install_package(pack)}

completeFun <- function(data, desiredCols) {
  completeVec <- complete.cases(data[, desiredCols])
  return(data[completeVec, ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code for it:

```
packages <- c("dplyr", "gridBase", "gridExtra")
package_loader <- function(x){
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
        if (!identical((x[i], installed.packages()[x[i],1])){
            install.packages(x[i], dep = TRUE)
        } else {
            require(x[i], character.only = TRUE)
        }
    }
}
package_loader(packages)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library <- function(x){
  x = toString(substitute(x))
if(!require(x,character.only=TRUE)){
  install.packages(x)
  base::library(x,character.only=TRUE)
}}
```

This works with unquoted package names and is fairly elegant (cf. GeoObserver's answer)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted a one liner that I could run from the commandline (actually via a Makefile). Here is an example installing "VGAM" and "feather" if they are not already installed:

```
R -e 'for (p in c("VGAM", "feather")) if (!require(p, character.only=TRUE)) install.packages(p, repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")'
```

From within R it would just be:

```
for (p in c("VGAM", "feather")) if (!require(p, character.only=TRUE)) install.packages(p, repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

There is nothing here beyond the previous solutions except that:

- I keep it to a single line
- I hard code the [`repos`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.3/topics/install.packages) parameter (to avoid any popups asking about the mirror to use)
- I don't bother to define a function to be used elsewhere

Also note the important `character.only=TRUE` (without it, the [`require`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/library.html) would try to load the package `p`).

Answer (score 1):

Let me share a bit of madness:

```
c("ggplot2","ggsci", "hrbrthemes", "gghighlight", "dplyr") %>%  # What will you need to load for this script?
  (function (x) ifelse(t =!(x %in% installed.packages()), 
    install.packages(x[t]),
    lapply(x, require)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new-ish package (I am a codeveloper), `Require`, that is intended to be part of a reproducible workflow, meaning *the function produces the same output the first time it is run or subsequent times*, i.e., the end-state is the same regardless of starting state. The following installs any missing packages (I include `require = FALSE` to strictly address the original question... normally I leave this on the default because I will generally want them loaded to the search path).

These two lines are at the top of every script I write (adjusting the package selection as necessary), allowing the script to be used by anybody in any condition (including any or all dependencies missing).

```
if (!require("Require")) install.packages("Require")
Require::Require(c("ggplot2", "Rcpp"), require = FALSE)
```

You can thus use this in your script or pass it anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Is really nobody using `librarian`?

```
# install.packages("librarian") # install if you do not have it
librarian::shelf(Rcpp, tidyverse/ggplot2)
```

As you can see it even can install from github without quotation marks making it more consistent. Furthermore, it can install bioconductor packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
  packages_installed <- function(pkg_list){
        pkgs <- unlist(pkg_list)
        req <- unlist(lapply(pkgs, require, character.only = TRUE))
        not_installed <- pkgs[req == FALSE]
        lapply(not_installed, install.packages, 
               repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")# add lib.loc if needed
        lapply(pkgs, library, character.only = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pckg=c("shiny","ggplot2","dplyr","leaflet","lubridate","RColorBrewer","plotly","DT","shinythemes")

for(i in 1:length(pckg)) 
   {
      print(pckg[i])
      if (!is.element(pckg[i], installed.packages()[,1]))
      install.packages(pckg[i], dep = TRUE)
      require(pckg[i], character.only = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standing on the shoulders of [@MichaelChirico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62809204/435004):

```
stopifnot(3 == length(find.package(c('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))))
```