# Load multiple packages at once

Tags: r, package

How can I load a bunch of packages at once with out retyping the require command over and over?  I've tried three approaches all of which crash and burn.

Basically, I want to supply a vector of package names to a function that will load them.

```
x<-c("plyr", "psych", "tm")

require(x)
lapply(x, require)
do.call("require", x)
```

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Several permutations of your proposed functions do work -- but only if you specify the `character.only` argument to be `TRUE`. Quick example:

```
lapply(x, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Tommy & daroczig -- Cool. That's a far cleaner solution. I'll leave mine up only for posterity, and for what it shows about why the OP's attempts didn't work.

Comment: You can take advantage of the partial character matching and get away with lapply(x, require, ch = T) or even lapply(x, require, c = T)

Comment: @daroczig This code loads the packages but why does it give the following Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘x’
2: In if (!loaded) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @Anusha: I have no idea ATM, what you have in your `x`?

Comment: @daroczig I am just running code given here. Changed do.call command to do.call("require", list(x)) otherwise it wouldnt run. If it helps, using rstudio.

Comment: @Anusha: I must miss something obvious, but I have never typed `do.call` in my answer, so I am a bit puzzled about your reply.

Comment: @daroczig Sorry. I thought you were adding character.only=T to the code given in question. And the next answer by Josh also included the do.call command. Maybe an edit can clarify for other readers.

Comment: @daroczig: can this be extended, adding a install call of any missing packages from the list provided by x?

Comment: @PauloCardoso: sure, but that might be longer then a one-liner :) Basically you should check the returned value of `require` and run `install.packages` if that results to `FALSE`, and `require` again. Please open a new question (and possibly link here) if you'd get stuck.

Comment: @daroczig: thanks. I think this would do the job: new.packs <- packs[!(packs %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packs)) install.packages(new.packs)
lapply(new.packages, require, character.only=T). Combining your and Shane example from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them?lq=1)

Comment: @PauloCardoso: that's right. Although I would have thought rather something like `lapply(x, function(x) {if (!require(x, character.only=T)) {install.packages(x);require(x)}})` to save any prior checks and do the install stuff only on demand. If we specify a list of packages to be loaded (and installed if needed) in `x` character - just like the OP asked. But it's getting pretty long to develop this further in a comment :)

Comment: Be nice if R::base added this `lapply` trick native to `library()`.

Be great to be able say: `library(c("plyr", "umx"))`

Answer (score 87):

The CRAN package **pacman** that I maintain (authored with Dason Kurkiewicz) can accomplish this:

So the user could do:

```
## install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(dplyr, psych, tm)
```

and if the package is missing `p_load` will download it from CRAN or Bioconductor.

Comment: +1! Why did you choose the short name `p_load`? A more descriptive name such as `load_packages` makes the intent of the function more clear.

Comment: Because the p stands for package.  Every function in the package that is useful and exported starts with `p_`.  Plus we tend to use library a bit and that's an additional 7 characters.  7 characters x ~1000000 life time uses of the function x .5 seconds per character = 3500000 seconds.  That's 58333.33 minutes, 972.2222 hours or 40.50926 days of a programmer's life we've given back to them :-)  In any event our goal is to push to CRAN by Feb 1

Comment: About a year late but we finally submitted to CRAN.  Should be up in a few days. @trinker (or me) make sure to modify this once it  goes public.

Comment: @Tyler I know I’m years late but I find your rationale for the `p_` prefix rather dubious. If terseness is the issue, remove the `p_` prefix entirely. In fact, having such prefixes are generally discouraged in other languages for good reasons (I’ve told Hadley they same with regards to his `fct_` nonsense in forcats). This is *especially* true since the intended usage of th package is with a qualified namespace (`pacman::`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I can see the point but there are already many functions in common R packages including base packages with those names.  This guards against namespace conflicts.  You point out that I use the `pacman::` but it's silly to believe everyone will use a package in the way I do.  Like most everything there is a tradeoff.  Here the tradeoff is terseness vs. descriptiveness vs. namespace conflicts.  Plus at this point a change like this would break too many people's code.

Comment: @TylerRinker Apologies for being combative on this issue, but I truly think that the R community is simply wrong here, and virtually every other modern language gets it right: You say “This guards against namespace conflicts.” — But *this is what namespaces are for!* The onus on package writers is to educate people to use the packages properly, not to accommodate their sloppy programming practices.

Comment: Cool! I guess this solves questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/9341635/1169233 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090169/1169233 (I see you've posted an answer to the latter, but not to the former, which is closed anyway).

Comment: @TylerRinker, thanks a lot for the convenient solution - is there also a way to use `p_load()` on a string vector of packages, say `pks <- c("devtools", "tidyverse")`?

Comment: @Ivo `character.only = TRUE` or `p_load(char = pks)`

Comment: [This approach](https://www.mitchelloharawild.com/blog/loading-r-packages-in-a-loop/) from Mitchell O'Hara-Wild is useful

Answer (score 25):

This should do the trick:

```
lapply(x, FUN = function(X) {
    do.call("require", list(X)) 
})
```

(The key bit is that the `args` argument in `do.call(what, args)` **must** be a list --- even if it only has a single element!)

Answer (score 21):

I think the code that @daroczig has provided can be improved by replacing the `require` with `library` and wrapping the `lapply` call inside the `invisible()` function. So, the improved code will look like the following:

```r
invisible(lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE))
```

This code is improved because:

1. `library()` is generally preferred over `require()` for loading packages because the former gives an error if the package is not installed while the latter just gives a warning. Moreover, `require()` calls `library()`, so why not just use `library()` directly!

   ```r
   library("time")
   # Error in library("time") : there is no package called ‘time’

   require("time")
   # Loading required package: time
   # Warning message:
   # In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
   # there is no package called ‘time’
   ```
2. The list object returned and printed by the `lapply()` call is not meaningful in this case, so it makes sense to make the output invisible. Say you use R Notebook for your analysis work, using the `invisible()` function will suppress the contents of the list object and prevent the clutter in the rendered notebook file.

Comment: Thanks for this. In Rmd I set `include=F` for this code chunk to remove the messy list of `TRUE` outputs from the @daroczig solution, but adding `invisible()` is notebook agnostic, so your addition is preferred.

Answer (score 20):

For someone who wants to install and load packages simultaneously I came across this function from this [link](https://gist.github.com/stevenworthington/3178163)

```
# ipak function: install and load multiple R packages.
# check to see if packages are installed. Install them if they are not, then load them into the R session.

ipak <- function(pkg){
new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
if (length(new.pkg)) 
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

# usage
packages <- c("ggplot2", "plyr", "reshape2", "RColorBrewer", "scales", "grid")
ipak(packages)
```

Comment: Hello I created a R file from your given snippet.
When I run that script on Amazon EMR service it gives me following output
as specified in following URL.
http://pastie.org/10402378#3,10-11,13.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative option comes from the package `easypackages` (requires installation). You can load packages in the most intuitive way:

```
library("easypackages")
libraries("plyr", "psych", "tm")
```

The package also includes a function to install several packages:

```
packages("plyr", "psych", "tm")
```

Reference [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/easypackages/README.html).

Comment: The function name is rather confusing/confused. “library”, in the `library` function, refers to the location where packages are installed: the *package library*. Loading several packages via `libraries` makes no sense. Having a separate function `packages` that does something else just makes this worse. I know naming is a hard problem in software engineering but really. These names are particularly bad.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I disagree that the name `libraries` makes no sense. It's the plural of `library`, and `library` loads a single package; `libraries` loads a plurality of packages. If you think of `library` as meaning "load from your single library", and extend that to `libraries` meaning "load from multiple libraries", then it's perhaps unintuitive, but that's not the intent; I would be quite happy with the name `libraries`.

Comment: @JamieS But it’s *still* (usually) loading from a single library. You seem to confuse library and package (which, to be fair, has become common in R): The “R library”, as my previous comment stated, refers to the location(s) (directory/directories) where R packages are installed. In this answer’s example, “plyr”, “psych” and “tm” are *not* libraries: they are packages.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use lubripack package and it neatly installs new packages and then load all of them in one line.

```
lubripack("plyr", "psych", "tm")
```

Here is the output after you run above code in RStudio.

[image]

## How to Install Package:

Run below code to download the package and install it from GitHub. No need to have GitHub Account.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("espanta/lubripack")
```

Comment: I would guess using images instead of text

Comment: This also does not answer the question in a way not already answered and seems to mostly be self promotion.

Comment: You are right, I tried to implicitly answer the question. Lets make it explicit hoping it can be answer to question.

Comment: @TylerRinker How is that now?

Answer (score 3):

Building on daroczig's solution, if you do not want to specify a list as input you can use

```
# Foo
mLoad <- function(...) {
  sapply(sapply(match.call(), as.character)[-1], require, character.only = TRUE)
}

# Example 
mLoad(plyr, dplyr, data.table)
```

... which is shorter than

```
lapply(list('plyr', 'dplyr', 'data.table'), require, character.only = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following function:

```
mrip <- function(..., install = TRUE){
    reqFun <- function(pack) {
        if(!suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(require(pack, character.only = TRUE)))) {
            message(paste0("unable to load package ", pack,
                           ": attempting to download & then load"))
            install.packages(pack)
            require(pack, character.only = TRUE)
        }
    }
    lapply(..., reqFun)
}
```

This tries to load, and if it fails installs and then try to load again.

Answer (score 2):

Slight mod of Tyler Rinker's answer to add a check to install & load pacman:

```
#Install/load pacman
if(!require(pacman)){install.packages("pacman");require(pacman)}
#Install/load tons of packages
p_load(plyr,psych,tm)
```

I like the p_load solution because it avoids quoting!