# Pass a character arg. to detach

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use detach by pasting together arguments.  this should be an easy job but is not for me.  I knew it was time to ask for help when I thought about using `eval(parse())`

Normally if I load a package I can detach it as follows:

```
detach(package:reshape)
```

I want to do the same by passing the packahe name as a character vector.  Here's my attempt:

```
pack<-"reshape"
detach(paste("package:", pack, sep=""))
```

Yielding the following error:

```
> detach(paste("package:", pack, sep=""))
Error in detach(paste("package:", pack, sep = "")) : 
  invalid 'name' argument
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to another question: [Load multiple packages at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8175912/662787)

You need to supply the `character.only=TRUE` argument.

```
pack<-"reshape"
detach(paste("package:", pack, sep=""), character.only=TRUE)
```

Comment: I keep missing that character.only arg.  Thanks for the patience.  lesson learned.