# Check if R package is installed then load library

Tags: r

Our R scripts are used on multiple users on multiple computers and hence there are deviations in which packages are installed on each computer. To ensure that each script works for all users I would like to define a function pkgLoad which will first test if the package is installed locally before loading the library with suppressed startup messages. Using [Check for installed packages before running install.packages()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341635/how-can-i-check-for-installed-r-packages-before-running-install-packages) as a guide, I tried

```
 pkgLoad <- function(x)
  {
    if (!require(x,character.only = TRUE))
    {
      install.packages(x,dep=TRUE, repos='http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/')
      if(!require(x,character.only = TRUE)) stop("Package not found")
    }
    #now load library and suppress warnings
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(x))
    library(x)
  }
```

When I try to load ggplot2 using pkgLoad("ggplot2") I get the following error message in my terminal

> Error in paste("package", package, sep = ":") :
> object 'ggplot2' not found
> > pkgLoad("ggplot2")
> Loading required package: ggplot2
> Error in library(x) : there is no package called ‘x’
> > pkgLoad("ggplot2")
> Error in library(x) : there is no package called ‘x’

Any why x changes from ggplot2 to plain old x?

Comment: Looks to me like those last two calls to `library` are redundant -- at that point the package should be loaded already if it exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `library(x,character.only=TRUE)`. Also you don't need the last line as  `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(x,character.only=TRUE))` already loads the package.

EDIT: @LarsKotthoff is right, you already load the package inside of the if brackets. There you already use option character.only=TRUE so everything is good if you just remove last to lines of your function body.

Answer (score 17):

I wrote this function the other day that I thought would be useful...

```
install_load <- function (package1, ...)  {   

   # convert arguments to vector
   packages <- c(package1, ...)

   # start loop to determine if each package is installed
   for(package in packages){

       # if package is installed locally, load
       if(package %in% rownames(installed.packages()))
          do.call('library', list(package))

       # if package is not installed locally, download, then load
       else {
          install.packages(package)
          do.call("library", list(package))
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you creating this function. I have made some changes to the function and released it on GitHub (https://github.com/iembry-USGS/install.load).

Comment: You're very welcome. My next step will be to have the package released to CRAN.

Comment: The package repository has been changed to https://gitlab.com/iembry/install.load. It is also located in CRAN. I will be making another update to the package soon.

Answer (score 14):

The CRAN **pacman** package that I maintain can address this nicely. Using the following header (to ensure **pacman** is installed first) and then the `p_load` function will try to load the package and then get them from CRAN if R can't load the package.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)
p_load(qdap, ggplot2, fakePackage, dplyr, tidyr)
```

Comment: Can p_load print warnings (functions masked by other packages)?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this nice function:
[klick](https://github.com/gimoya/theBioBucket-Archives/blob/master/R/Functions/instant_pkgs.R)

Answer (score 2):

The following can be used:

```
check.and.install.Package<-function(package_name){
    if(!package_name%in%installed.packages()){
        install.packages(package_name)
    }
}

check.and.install.Package("RTextTools")
check.and.install.Package("e1071")
```

Answer (score 1):

Though @maloneypatr function works fine, but it is quite silent and does not respond on success of packages loaded. I built below function that does make some checks on user entry and also respond on the number of packages being successfully installed.

```
lubripack <- function(...,silent=FALSE){

  #check names and run 'require' function over if the given package is installed
  requirePkg<- function(pkg){if(length(setdiff(pkg,rownames(installed.packages())))==0)
                                    require(pkg, quietly = TRUE,character.only = TRUE)
                            }

  packages <- as.vector(unlist(list(...)))
  if(!is.character(packages))stop("No numeric allowed! Input must contain package names to install and load")

  if (length(setdiff(packages,rownames(installed.packages()))) > 0 )
     install.packages(setdiff(packages,rownames(installed.packages())),
                      repos = c("https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/", "http://owi.usgs.gov/R/"))

  res<- unlist(sapply(packages, requirePkg))

  if(silent == FALSE && !is.null(res)) {cat("\nBellow Packages Successfully Installed:\n\n")
                    print(res)
                   }
}
```

## Note 1:

If `silent = TRUE`(all capital silent), it installs and loads packages without reporting. If `silent = FALSE`, it reports successful installation of packages. Default value is `silent = FALSE`

## How to use

```
lubripack(“pkg1","pkg2",.,.,.,.,"pkg")
```

## Example 1: When all packages are valid and mode is not silent

```
lubripack(“shiny","ggvis")
```

or

```
lubripack(“shiny","ggvis", silent = FALSE)
```

## Output

[image]

## Example 2: When all packages are valid and mode is silent

```
lubripack(“caret","ggvis","tm", silent = TRUE)
```

## Output 2

[image]

## Example 3: When package cannot be found

```
lubripack(“shiny","ggvis","invalidpkg", silent=FALSE)
```

## Output 3

[image]

---

## How to Install Package:

Run below code to download the package and install it from GitHub. No need to have GitHub Account.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("espanta/lubripack")
```