# Can I make R install packages automatically?

Tags: r

When running a script with new libraries, I will automatically respond to the error message `Error in library(x) : there is no package called ‘x’` with `install.packages("x")`. Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(! require("x")) install.packages("x")
```

but see [Check if R package is installed then load library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155814/check-if-r-package-is-installed-then-load-library?rq=1) for more robust solutions