# R How to check if some of the loaded packages are not used at all through a script

Tags: r, package

I have an 600 line script in R which I've been editing many times by cutting and adding entire chunks.
The script loads ~20 packages at the beginning and now I don't know if all of them end up being used.
Therefore  I have the following practical questions:

- Will removing unnecessary packages improve performance/memory usage?
- If yes, how can I check and remove packages that are loaded but not end up being used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell what packages you have used in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513444/how-to-tell-what-packages-you-have-used-in-r)