# How can I see what are packages being used for in an R script, and which packages are currently not used?

Tags: r, optimization, package

I am inheriting some code and I think there is room for housekeeping, which includes tidying up the packages game.

In particular, I want both to see what are loaded packages used for, and (most importantly) if there are any loaded-but-unused packages.

The code is long and the packages are many, so I would definitely prefer to automate this process.

As a small example, if I had:

```
packageload <- c("ggplot2", "readxl")
lapply(packageload, library, character.only = TRUE)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut)) +
  geom_bar()
```

I would want some output telling me that `ggplot()` is used from `ggplot2` (which is therefore being used as package), and that `readxl` is currently not used in the project code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been looking for a clear answer to this and finally, building on the useful function pointed out by @eh21 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009440/12391423), I built up this small approach that fits the intention with 3 lines of code and that can be replicated by anyone (and with this I mean by non-experienced programmes like me) on their case with no effort.

The principle is to use this approach after the packages have been loaded and before the actual project code (i.e. no need for it to be run in order to get the desired information), as below:

```
# Load packages ----

packageload <- c("ggplot2", "readxl")
lapply(packageload, library, character.only = TRUE)


# Find which packages do used functions belong to ----

used.functions <- NCmisc::list.functions.in.file(filename = "thisfile.R", alphabetic = FALSE) |> print()


# Find which loaded packages are not used ----

used.packages <- used.functions |> names() |> grep(pattern = "packages:", value = TRUE) |> gsub(pattern = "package:", replacement = "") |> print()

unused.packages <- packageload[!(packageload %in% used.packages)] |> print()


# Actual project code (no need to be run) ----

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut)) +
  geom_bar()
```

The relevant outputs are:

```
> used.packages
[1] "base"    "ggplot2"

> used.functions
$`character(0)`
[1] "list.functions.in.file"

$`package:base`
[1] "c"      "lapply" "print"  "names"  "grep"   "gsub"   

$`package:ggplot2`
[1] "ggplot"   "aes"      "geom_bar"

> unused.packages
[1] "readxl"
```

Notes:

- This requires `install.packages("NCmisc")`, however I didn't load that package (and used `::` instead) for consistency, as it shouldn't appear among the `used.packages`;
- if using RStudio and wanting to apply this to multiple scripts, using `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path` instead of `"thisfile.R"` in `NCmisc::list.functions.in.file` will be handy.
- The approach above works for the case in which `lapply()` is used on a named object to load packages. If packages are instead loaded without resorting to a named object (e.g. with a series of `library()` or `require()`), the ****# Load packages ----**** section of the code above can be modified as follows:

```
# Load packages ----

packageload <- search()

library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

packageload <- search()[!(search() %in% packageload)] |> grep(pattern = "package:", value = TRUE) |> gsub(pattern = "package:", replacement = "")
```

Comment: Great approach, but this only works for me if I replace ```grep(pattern = "packages:", value = TRUE)``` with ```grep(pattern = "package:", value = TRUE)```.