# How to make if statement to check whether a R package is installed or not in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a personal R-function.

I want add if statement which can check whether essential R packages are installed.

I used exist() function but its purpose is to examine existence of an object
so it didn't work.

Is there a basic command for checking existence of a specific R-package in R?

Thx

Comment: Why not using `library()` or `require()`?

Comment: The answer lies [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341635/check-for-installed-packages-before-running-install-packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `installed.packages()` That will list all installed packages. Another option is `require(thepackage)` which will either load the package or return FALSE if the 'thepackage' is not available.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do specifically what you asked is

`"Package-Name" %in% installed.packages()`
which will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether or not "Package-Name" is installed.

However, if you're writing a script, you will usually want to use

`library(Package-Name)` or `require(Package-Name)`

If the package is installed, both will load it. If it isn't, `library` will throw an error, `require` will return `FALSE` and give a warning.