# Load package at start-up

Tags: r, rstudio, startup

I am trying to load a package at start-up if it's already installed. If it isn't then I want to first install it and then load it. So, I created the following function:

```
RLoadPackage <- function(packname)
{
  if((packname %in% rownames(installed.packages()))==FALSE)
  {
    install.packages(packname,dependencies = TRUE)
  } 
  library(packname,character.only = TRUE)
}
```

This works well once RStudio is opened, but it doesn't quite work at start-up. I added this function to my local .RProfile file as:

```
RLoadPackage("ggplot2")

RLoadPackage <- function(packname)
{
  if((packname %in% rownames(installed.packages()))==FALSE)
  {
    install.packages(packname,dependencies = TRUE)
  } 
  library(packname,character.only = TRUE)
}
```

However, I get the error message as:

```
Error: could not find function "RLoadPackage"
```

One option is to install packages manually and then add a bunch of `library("xyz")`

However, the above option is very clunky. So, I created a function.

I've 2 questions:

**1) Can someone please help me with it?**

**2) Is there more efficient way of doing this?**

My post is inspired from the following two links:
1) [Check for installed packages before running install.packages()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341635/check-for-installed-packages-before-running-install-packages)
2) http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Check out `help(".First")`.

Comment: @Richard Scriven and Shayaa--I believe I read your mind! I just thought that R is sequentially processing functions. So, I defined the function before everything else, and it worked. However, I'm looking for more efficient code--if you are aware of any method to load 10-15 packages and do what I am trying to do. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Isn't your "Error: could not find function..." simply due to the fact that you call `RLoadPackage("ggplot2")` before defining `RLoadPackage`?

Comment: Yes!  that is correct

Answer (score -1):

Ok. This piece of code works:

```
library("utils")

RLoadPackage <- function(packname)
{
  if((packname %in% rownames(installed.packages()))==FALSE)
  {
    install.packages(packname,dependencies = TRUE)
  } 
  library(packname,character.only = TRUE)
}

RLoadPackage("ggplot2")
RLoadPackage("dplyr")
RLoadPackage("lubridate")
```

However, is there more efficient way of loading multiple packages--maybe a vectorized version of this? I am just curious.

Comment: [an oldie but goodie](https://gist.github.com/stevenworthington/3178163)