# Divert output of require()

Tags: r

I use this code in my Rprofile.site to load packages when I start R.

```
pkg <- c("dplyr", "tidyr", "crayon", "xlsx")
apply(as.matrix(pkg), 1, function(x) {
    if (!x %in% utils::installed.packages()) {
        utils::install.packages(x)
        cat(paste0("package ", x, " installed\n"))
    }
    x <- require(x, character.only = T)
})
```

It works just fine but prints `[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE` to the console. I know I can divert `stdout` using `textConnection(); sink(); [code]; sink(); close()`, but that seems like a lot of work. Is there a way to do this with less typing?

```
tc <- textConnection("outputs","w")
sink(tc, type="output")
    pkg <- c("dplyr", "tidyr", "crayon", "xlsx")
    apply(as.matrix(pkg), 1, function(x) {
        if (!x %in% utils::installed.packages()) {
            utils::install.packages(x)
            cat(paste0("package ", x, " installed\n"))
        }
        require(x, character.only = T)
    })
sink(NULL, type="output")
close(tc)
```

Comment: You just want to not print `TRUE` to the console? Can you just use `library()`?

Comment: @Calum You, I probably can just use `library()`. I used `require()` because of this comment in the `library()` documentation: "`require` is designed for use inside other functions; it returns FALSE and gives a warning (rather than an error as `library()` does by default) if the package does not exist". Since I'm only loading packages I know I've installed, `library()` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. You can use `invisible` on the output from `apply` to remove the outputs.
2. Or you can use the `pacman` package to perform what you are doing.
3. Or the below code should be more concise (See 
   [Check for installed packages before running install.packages()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341635/check-for-installed-packages-before-running-install-packages)):

```
invisible(lapply(pkg, function(x) {
    if (!nzchar(system.file(package=x)))
        install.packages(x)
    library(x, character.only=TRUE)
}))
```

4. Or write an R package to make your dependencies explicit.

Comment: `invisible(apply())` worked perfectly. Thanks. -edit- And now I'm installing `pacman`! -edit-