# Check if package is installed without loading

Tags: r, r-package

The typical way a package developer is advised to check whether a user has installed a package is like this:

```
if (!requireNamespace("package")) {
  stop("Please install package.")
}
```

`requireNamespace` loads the package (in the current scope?) and returns a TRUE/FALSE value. I need to check the install state of a package without loading the namespace.

The reason for this is because I am writing a `knit_print` S3 method (extending the `knitr` package) and the namespace I am checking for `kableExtra` has side effects outside of the context of my `knit_print` method that I want to avoid.

When loaded, `kableExtra` changes how subsequent calls to `knitr::kable` are formatted at the global level. It has good reasons for doing so, but I want to use `kableExtra` inside my S3 method and not have end users confused about why `kable` behaves differently after my `knit_print` method is called.

That's why I want to do the check for the namespace (and if `kableExtra` is not installed, just call `knitr::normal_print`) without loading the namespace.

**Edit:** To clarify why I don't think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them), those answers do not pay any special attention to whether the solution *loads* the package when it is installed. It turns out that some of the solutions do not load the package in question, but they are not clearly differentiated.

Comment: `?installed.packages`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082613/1989480 for a faster method

Answer (score 8):

Use `installed.packages`.

```
if ("kableExtra" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) {
    # do something
}
```