# Unexpected behaviour of R "library" function with function args as parameters

Tags: r

What I'm trying to do is plain straight forward:

```
required_pkgs <- c("A", "B", "C")

for (pkg in required_pkgs) {
   library(pkg)
}
```

At runtime, the R interpreter tries to lookup (3 times) a package called "pkg" (and of course it fails at the first try), when I do expect it to be either "A", "B", "C".

Of course My ignorance of the language makes me miss the point, but why it behaves like that? Does R expects me to write the following code:

```
library(A)
library(B)
library(C)
```

I do need to iterate over each package loading to handle missing packages and fallback to installing it or pick an alternative.

**BASICALLY** I was whining for not being able to iterate over the array of packages names and each call to `library` with the `for` parameter (`pkg`) resulted in R trying to load a non-existent `pkg` library. This is solved by adding the `character.only=TRUE` argument a the invocation of `library`.

EDIT: more infos, sorry for being so vague...

Comment: Found the answer by myself here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/library.html and the param `character.only` will solve my issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175912/load-multiple-packages-at-once

Comment: Thank you @zx8754! That's a good one. Probably the answer to this question/doubt would be my own previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

You saved A,B and C in required_pkgs then modify your code as: library(required_pkgs[pkg]) in for loop instead of library(pkg)

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer; some thing like : `required_pkgs=c("A","B","C"); for(pkg in required_pkgs) library(required_pkgs[pkg])` doesn't do what I was looking after (loading "A", "B", "C")

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you wanna install three packages at a time, you can use following code of R:
install.packages(c("A", "B", "C")),
still if its not gonna work elaborate your question properly.

Comment: My first comment resolves my question. I fell in panic before reading accurately the docs, even though is counter intuitive. I should have forgotten `for` and go straight to `library(required_pkgs)`.