# load multiple packages AND supress messages

Tags: r

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175912/load-multiple-packages-at-once) post.
And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681688/disable-messages-upon-loading-a-package) one.

I would like to load packages in a oner and supress `suppressPackageStartupMessages` at the same time.

The answer in the first link uses lapply:

```
packages <- c("tidyverse", "qdap", "stringr", "stringi", "textstem", "foreach", "caret", "xgboost", "quanteda")
lapply(packages, require, character.only = T)
```

This returns an unsightly list to the console:

```
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE

[[4]]
[1] TRUE
```

Plus, I would like to also get rid of those messages that are sent to the console on load e.g.

```
> library(tidyverse)
Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
Loading tidyverse: dplyr
Conflicts with tidy packages --------------------------------------------------------------------
accumulate(): purrr, foreach
filter():     dplyr, stats
lag():        dplyr, stats
when():       purrr, foreach
```

Is there a clever, short way to both load a vector of packages AND suppressPackageStartupMessages?

Comment: Here you have a function in github that may help you: https://gist.github.com/stevenworthington/3178163

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option would be

```
pacman::p_load(packages)
```

Comment: To do that would I have to load pacman first ```library(pacman)``` and then load all the other libraries using pacman? Obviously an extra line of code is no biggie, but the goal, if I'm being pedantic, is to neatly call all packages in a oner.

Comment: @DougFir  In my plain new console, I do `pacman::p_load(reshape2, stringr, overflow, data.table, dplyr, tidyr, purrr)` and it loads all these packages in one single step and no warnings

Comment: Ah right, because library:: is like calling the library one time right?

Comment: This is nice too, if `pacman` is already installed or someone can install it.

Answer (score 14):

You could do the following

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(ggplot2)
    library(tidyr)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I would go with:

```
packages <- c("tidyverse", "qdap", "stringr", "stringi", "textstem", "foreach", "caret", "xgboost", "quanteda")

zzz<-lapply(packages, function(xxx) suppressMessages(require(xxx, character.only = TRUE,quietly=TRUE,warn.conflicts = FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of the package messages, you can use `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` or you can use the `quietly = T` option:

```
packages <- c("tidyverse","stringr")
lapply(packages, function(x)require(x, character.only = T, quietly = T))
```

To get rid of the list input as well, you can wrap the whole thing in the `invisible()` function:

```
packages <- c("tidyverse","stringr")
invisible(lapply(packages, function(x) require(x, character.only = T, quietly = T)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, never knew about invisible. Went with amonk's answer for no reason other than timing