# R aes function runs in R but not in r markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have encountered a strange problem with Markdown.

I attach hereunder the R code included in markdown for generating a correlation heatmap.

```
library(reshape2)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
data("cars")

    # Get lower triangle of the correlation matrix
get_lower_tri<-function(cormat){
  cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- NA
  return(cormat)
}
# Get upper triangle of the correlation matrix
get_upper_tri <- function(cormat){
  cormat[lower.tri(cormat)]<- NA
  return(cormat)
}

reorder_cormat <- function(cormat){
  # Use correlation between variables as distance
  dd <- as.dist((1-cormat)/2)
  hc <- hclust(dd)
  cormat <-cormat[hc$order, hc$order]
}

cormat <- round(cor(cars),2)

upper_tri <- get_upper_tri(cormat)

# Reorder the correlation matrix
cormat <- reorder_cormat(cormat)

upper_tri <- get_upper_tri(cormat)

# Melt the correlation matrix
melted_cormat <- melt(upper_tri, na.rm = TRUE)

# Create a ggheatmap
ggheatmap <- ggplot(melted_cormat, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value))+
  geom_tile(color = "white")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white", 
                       midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1,1), space = "Lab", 
                       name="Pearson\nCorrelation") +
  theme_minimal()+ # minimal theme
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
                                   size = 12, hjust = 1))+
  coord_fixed()

ggheatmap + 
  geom_text(aes(Var2, Var1, label = value), color = "black", size = 4) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    legend.justification = c(1, 0),
    legend.position = c(0.6, 0.7),
    legend.direction = "horizontal")+
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 7, barheight = 1,
                               title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5))
```

The code runs perfectly in R console but when kitted with markdown it returns this error.

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Var2' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... by_layer -> f -> <Anonymous> -> f -> lapply -> FUN -> FUN
Execution halted
```

The problem seems to be in the aes function (ggplot). For some reasons it's not able to find the "Var2" present in the `melt_cormap` object

Any advice?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't see `Var2` defined anywhere in your sample code. Can you show where in the scope of the code it is defined?

Comment: Do you have do you have library(reshape2) in your markdown code?

Comment: @GaryWeissman I don't understand your comment. Obviously, `Var2` should be a column of `melted_cormat`.

Comment: Does it change smthg if you use `aes(x=Var2, y=Var1, fill = value)` ?

Comment: @Roland I don't see any data here, so I can't tell what is actually in `melted_cormat` or `upper_tri` or anything else. Providing actual data with a reproducible example will often help to identify the problem.

Comment: @Vlo yes, both reshape and reshape2.

Comment: @DJack: nope. same error

Comment: it's probably not wise to use both, but if you have to, then you should be specific with e.g. the `melt` function, i.e. `reshape2::melt` it that's the one you want

Comment: @Roland you can use the Car dataset o the Wine one dropping the factors variables

Comment: @AlbertoStefanelli please see this post on creating a reproducible example, especially the section on Producing a Minimal Dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @GaryWeissman , thanks. corrected

Comment: Which `aes` call is failing? Is it the original heatmap, or when you try to add `geom_text`?

Comment: @AlbertoStefanelli It runs fine for me once I load all packages. As far as I know, `library` does not take multiple arguments for libraries to load. Is there an error there when you run the code in markdown?

Comment: @Pdubbs the geom_text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `library` function does not take multiple library names as arguments although doesn't seem to throw an error. You probably have all the libraries loaded in the console, but when `knitr` runs it does so in a new environment and needs to load them all anew.

Try this at the top of your code:

`library(reshape2)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)`

If you want to load them all in a single line, there is already a SO post about that here:

[Load multiple packages at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175912/load-multiple-packages-at-once)

Comment: I am using pacman as a manager. The code there reported is wrong but it just for reproducibility purposes. In any case, thanks for this, i will correct)

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this, the problem was pacman. For some reason, was not loading the packages properly, I switched back to the baseline command and the issues is resolved. Thanks to everyone