# Command describe unrecognized even if the package psych is loaded

Tags: r, psych

I'm using Rstudio 2022.22.1 on MacOS Monterey 12.3.1.

I load libraries at the begininning by doing:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library("tidyverse", "here", "magrittr")
library("pastecs", "psych")
## dlf<-read.delim("data/DownloadFestival(No Outlier).dat", header=TRUE)

dlf<-here::here("data/DownloadFestival(No Outlier).dat") %>% readr::read_delim(col_names = TRUE)
```

I also check the thick for the library "psych" in the *Packages* section of RStudio.

The issue is that, from a certain point (after Knitting) I wasn't unable to use the command `describe`, this is the error:

> could not find function "describe"

I could bypass this, by typing each time I use the function:

```r
psych::describe
```

instead of `describe` alone

How can I use `describe` without specifying the `psych::` prefix each time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `library("pastecs", "psych")` isn't doing what you think. Weirdly enough, there isn't an obvious idiom for "load a bunch of packages at once": I wish there were an easier way to do this, but try

```r
invisible(lapply(c("psych", "pastecs"), library, character.only = TRUE))
```

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175912/load-multiple-packages-at-once) provide a bunch of different ways to load many packages at once (the accepted answer is the same as the one given here).

Comment: Thanks, that explains why if I put together all the 4 libraries I get another error too.