# Check for installed packages in R

Tags: r, r-package

Based on the answer to this question: [Elegant way to check for missing packages and install them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them)

I'm using the following code to make sure that all packages are installed when I upgrade R, or set up other users:

```
list.of.packages <- c("RODBC", "reshape2", "plyr")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
```

I've placed it in my .First function in my .Rprofile, but when I start up R it gives the following error and continues starting up:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  could not find function "installed.packages"
```

If I run the code after I get a prompt it works fine. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears from reading `?Startup` that:

> Next, if a function .First is found on the search path, it is executed
>   as .First(). Finally, function .First.sys() in the base package is
>   run. This calls require to attach the default packages specified by
>   options("defaultPackages").

Now, `installed.packages` is in the **utils** package, which is typically one of the default packages. So it's not available at the time `.First` is called.

Perhaps try replacing `installed.packages` with `utils::installed.packages`?

As Josh notes below my eyes skimmed over the piece that addresses this issue directly, namely:

> Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced only the
>   base package is loaded, so objects in other packages need to be
>   referred to by e.g. utils::dump.frames or after explicitly loading the
>   package concerned.

Comment: Or (as described a bit earlier in `?Startup`, you can use `utils::installed.packages` or first explicitly load the package with `require(utils)`.

Comment: Awesome. Referencing the functions as utils::installed.packages and utils::install.packages does the trick. Thanks Josh and Joran!