# When does 'quietly = TRUE' actually work in the require() function?

Tags: r

I am trying to code a set of functions to check for missing R packages, and to install them if necessary. There's some good code to do that at StackOverflow: [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them?lq=1).

I would like to make the functions as silent as possible, especially since R returns even successful messages in red ink. Accordingly, I have tried to pass the `quietly = TRUE` argument to both `library` and `require`.

However, these options never seem to work:

```
# attempt to get a silent fail
require(xyz, quietly = TRUE)
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘xyz’
```

**How can I get `require` to fail silently, and what am I not getting about the `quietly` option?**

The documentation says:

> `quietly` a logical. If TRUE, no message confirming package loading is printed, and most often, no errors/warnings are printed if package loading fails.

But it seems to me "most often" should be "almost never" in my personal experience. I would happily hear about your experience with that. Rationale: coding functions to help students.

---

**Add.** The same question applies to `quiet = TRUE` in `install.packages()`. It kills only the progress bar, but not the "downloaded binary packages are in" message (printed in black, yay!) that follows, even though it has no use to the median user.

---

**Add.** In case this might be of interest to anyone, the code so far:

```
## getPackage(): package loader/installer
getPackage <- function(pkg, load = TRUE, silent = FALSE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org") {
  if(!suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(require(pkg, character.only = TRUE, quietly = TRUE)))) {
    try(install.packages(pkg, repos = repos), silent = TRUE)
  }
  if(load) suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, quietly = TRUE))
  if(load & !silent) message("Loaded ", pkg)
}

## Not run:
x <- c("ggplot2", "devtools") # etc.
lapply(x, getPackage, silent = TRUE)
```

I'm thinking of just quitting the effort to use `quietly` in the function above, given that it does not seem to work when expected. I should probably ask the R userlists about that to get an explanation from the core devteam. The `suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(require(...)))` workaround can be unstable in my experience.

Comment: +1 for "most often" should be "almost never"!

Comment: You might want to read the source code for `require` and `library` to see exactly what `quietly` does.  Unfortunately those functions are a mess of spaghetti code.  Also read the source code for `install.packages` to see how complicated (unzip a file into a directory) you can make a simple process.

Comment: I have read the source for `require`: it's a lot of nested conditionals. The `quietly` argument kills additional error information, but does not suppress the `Loading...` messages. Students find it bothering, especially in red ink. One of R's idiosyncrasies. My favourite is the information passed by `install.packages` at the end, probably with `cat`: "The downloaded packages are now in (temporary and incomprehensible folder path)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution appears to be

```
try(library(xyz), silent=TRUE)
```

`require` is basically a wrapper around `tryCatch(library)`, so this just cuts out some extraneous code.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to make your `require` function **very** quiet, you can use :

```
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(require(xyz)))
```

Which gives :

...well, nothing :)

Comment: This is what I have ended up doing until now. However, it can be unstable: I have had RStudio abort my R session quite a few times when running this, especially through a `lapply` structure.

Comment: @Fr. Always check that sort of error outside of RStudio to make sure it isn't simply specific to that particular IDE.

Comment: I have checked it outside of RStudio, and it's stable in R64.

Comment: Then it sounds like the RStudio guys would probably like to hear about it, if it's a reproducible crash.  It doesn't happen for me with version 0.97.310 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I got the crashes while trying to install a 60+ list of packages through a code structure that I have rewritten since. If I manage to get a reproducible error, I'll certainly file a report about it.

Answer (score 21):

I'm not sure exactly when this was added to the language, but the preferred way to do this nowadays is

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    require(this)
    require(that)
    ...
})
```

This zorches "Loading ...", complaints about masking symbols, and other noise, but messages indicating actual problems still appear (e.g. a package or dependency is unavailable).

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to set warn options, before and after the call...

```
 options(warn=-1)
 try(require(xyz, quietly = TRUE),silent=TRUE)
 options(warn=0)
```

But this is dangerous.. I think what you need is to change the color of warning message.

Comment: This is indeed dangerous and not recommendable, although I agree that it works. But to me, it's just too hacky – almost as much as setting the warnings text to background color.

Comment: @Fr. I guess you want to hide this for yours no technical user.. I am trying to find an option to change the warning message to green for example..

Comment: God luck with that. For some reason, `message()` and `warning()` are printed identically. It's only with `cat()` that you can print neutral text. I don't think the colors are hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

```
PkgNames <- c("forecast", "tseries", "ggplot2", "qcc", "ggmap","corrgram",
              "effects", "Hmisc", "plyr", "reshape")
invisible(suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(lapply(PkgNames, require, character.only = T))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for the benefit of anyone else looking for an answer:

`requireNamespace` with `quietly=TRUE` seems to *quietly* check if the package is installed, so checking that can be quiet:

```
    > if (requireNamespace("Foobar", quietly = TRUE)) "Found it" else "Not found"
    [1] "Not found"
    > if (requireNamespace("utils", quietly = TRUE)) "Found it" else "Not found"
    [1] "Found it"
```

So to solve the OP's primary problem (the question in bold):

```
    if (requireNamespace("package", quietly=TRUE)) require("package", quietly=TRUE);
```

Any noise comes from loading the package.  The second `quietly=TRUE` helps somewhat.  So, the above is silent for missing packages, silent for some found packages, much less noisy than without `quietly` for others.  There are undoubtedly packages for which is doesn't help at all.