# Can you silently install Bioconductor packages?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm writing a pipeline in Snakemake that calls an R script. This R script has its own environment, with `r-base`, `r-ggplot2` and `r-biocmanager` in it. I also need the package [ggbio](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ggbio.html) that can be installed with `biocmanager`. I want to *silently* install this package when the script is called because I don't want it to flood my terminal. Is there a way to do this? I have this right now, but this still outputs instalment information to the terminal:

```
if(!require(ggbio, quietly=TRUE)){  # if the package is not there, install it
  BiocManager::install("ggbio")
  library(ggbio)
}
...
```

I also tried this which I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834841/when-does-quietly-true-actually-work-in-the-require-function):

```
if(!suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(require(ggbio, quietly=TRUE)))){
  BiocManager::install("ggbio")
  library(ggbio)
}

# OR
if(!require(ggbio, quietly=TRUE)){
  suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(BiocManager::install("ggbio")))
  library(ggbio)
}
...
```

But this also still outputs to the terminal. There also doesn't seem to be a way to give an argument like `quietly=TRUE` to `BiocManager::install("ggbio")`.

**EDIT:**
`invisible()`, `capture.output()` and `sink()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499400/suppress-automatic-output-to-console-in-r) also doesn't work:

```
# invisible(capture.output()) around install
if(!require(ggbio, quietly=TRUE)){
  invisible(capture.output(BiocManager::install("ggbio")))  # doesn't work
}

# invisible(capture.output()) around entire if.
invisible(capture.output(if(!require(ggbio, quietly=TRUE)){  # doesn't work
  BiocManager::install("ggbio")
}))

# sink() (Linux)
sink("/dev/null")  # doesn't work
if(!require(ggbio, quietly=TRUE)){
  BiocManager::install("ggbio")
}
sink()

# only invisible()
if(!require(ggbio, quietly=TRUE)){
  invisible(BiocManager::install("ggbio"))  # doesn't work
}
```

**EDIT 2**:
I learned that the Bioconductor packages are available in the bioconda channel so if you like me are using an `environment.yaml` file you can just list Bioconductor packages like so:

```
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - bioconda
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - r-base=4.1.1
 - r-ggplot2=3.3.5
 - bioconductor-ggbio
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress automatic output to console in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499400/suppress-automatic-output-to-console-in-r)

Comment: Unfortunately `capture.output()` also doesn't work.

Comment: Dang! Retracted close vote, hope you find someone to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must install the package quietly you can do:

```
suppressMessages({
if (!requireNamespace("ggbio", quietly = TRUE))
    BiocManager::install("ggbio", quiet = TRUE)
})
```

But it's always a good idea to see if anything goes wrong with the installation.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of surrounding the entire if with `suppressMessages()`; this indeed works, thanks!