# Easy way to reinstall entire packages on new machine

Tags: r, package, install.packages

How to install the same package on more than 1 machine (work and home etc.)?

Comment: Relevant post: [Elegant way to check for missing packages and install them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exporting all packages from R / Rstudio etc using an R data dump file:

```
ip <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())
dump("ip","ip.Rdmpd")
```

From here send the dump file to the new computer and read into R or Rstudio etc, whatever your preference is and then wait will all packages download and install from CRAN:

```
setwd("/path/to/dumpfile")
source("ip.Rdmpd")
install.packages(ip$Package)
```

Comment: SO is a Q/A site. So in future, please post questions in the questions section, while answers in the answer section- not both in the same place.