# R install packages without loading in .Rprofile

Tags: r

I want to make sure I always have my most commonly used R packages installed without my intervention. This is useful as I work across multiple computers, often reformat my computers, and sometimes have new packages that I want to add to this "commonly used" list and don't want to have to manually install it on every machine. Basically, I just want R to install missing packages for me whenever it starts up.

Currently I'm using a `.Rprofile` that installs my package list whenever I start R. It contains the following:

```
packages <- c("list", "of", "packages")

for (p in packages) {
  if(!suppressWarnings(require(p, character.only = TRUE))){
    utils::install.packages(p, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
  }
}
```

There are a couple of issues:

1. Running `install.packages` when the package is already installed seems to download the package (or meta data?) from the repo, and maybe attempts a reinstall
2. I'm using `require` to check whether a package is already installed, but that has the side effect of also loading the package. I don't want any package loading to happen, only install (if needed)

How do I set this up so that 1) a package will be installed if it isn't already, and 2) not load the package at startup? I think ultimately what I'm looking for is a way to check whether a package is installed without having to load it

I've considered two ways around this, but neither are ideal and would like to avoid them as solutions:

- Use a package manager like [Packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/). I'm not a fan of essentially creating managed virtual environments for all of my projects. It would take up unnecessary space to have multiple copies of the same package files on my machines
- A common solution to this problem (e.g. [Elegant way to check for missing packages and install them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them)) is to check whether a package is found in `installed.packages()`. But this ends up being really slow (which is especially a problem at startup) if you have a lot of installed packages

I've seen many questions about this, but all of the solutions I've seen either load packages using `require` or checks against `installed.packages()`. Is there another way?

Comment: Put all your packages in a shared drive or network filesystem, and point R there

Comment: Sometimes I use computers at work that don't have access to the same network that my personal desktop is on

Comment: Check [pacman](https://github.com/trinker/pacman) package out