# package is needed for this model and is not installed

Tags: r

I am using the train function of caret package with r.
If I specify a package that I have not installed, method displays the following.

```
1 package is needed for this model and is not installed. (***). Would you like to try to install it now?
1: yes
2: no
```

I would like to answer all "1: yes" without entering this question by hand every time, but how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

You should not look into installing inside `caret` `train` function but before it.

For example using:

```
list.of.packages <- c("your_package1", "your_package2")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
```

Source: [Elegant way to check for missing packages and install them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them)