# Installing some library twice in R

Tags: r

I wonder, can I do any harm to my system (or the stability of R installation) if I install some package twice. Or when installing a new package it will simply overwrite the previous version.

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue unless you install a package as an admin user, and again as a normal user. Then you will have a version in two different locations on your system. That could lead to issues when upgrading, or confusion as to which version is loaded.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Check if the [package is already installed before installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090169/680068)?

Comment: @xx8754, sometimes it happens by accident and just trying to accident what is the best way to proceed once something like this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me all the time that I execute `install.packages` on something that I have installed before. You just get a warning.

Comment: This is better left as a comment.

Comment: I am still not fully getting it, are saying there is not harm in doing it?