# How to install many R packages?

Tags: r, cran

I should install many different R packages.

I prepared the file `requirements.R` (example below):

```
install.packages("mongolite", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
install.packages("xgboost", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
```

How can I install all of them, for example, from command line?

Should I somehow use `devtools::load_all`?

Comment: `install.packages` is vectorized, you can pass in a character vector into `pkgs` argument

Comment: Alternatively just use the source("requirements.R") command...

Comment: `source("requirements.R")` is exactly what I need. But can I run it from command line or using `devtools`, so that in the script I can only do `library...`?

Comment: @David Arenburg: In your reommended posts I didn't find the answer to my question - how to install R packages from command line

Comment: @Fluxy Related post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090169/680068

Answer (score 1):

You can write a little function like this one, it also checks if the packages required are already installed and if that's the case it only loads them:

```
get.packages <- function(packages, Base_R_Best_R = F){
  if(Base_R_Best_R){
    print("No packages required!")
  }
  else{
  for(i in seq.int(length(packages))){
    if(!require(packages[i], character.only = T)){
      install.packages(packages[i])
    }
    library(packages[i], character.only = T)
  }
}
}
#example
#get.packages(c("dplyr", "installr", "Amelia")
```

**Edit**
Option to not install any packages as Base `R` is best `R`.

Comment: You need to decide if base R is the best R or you want to install packages :)

Comment: True to an extent haha, base `R` being the best does not mean that there cant be any good packages :)

Comment: I more inclined towards `source("requirements.R")`. Please see my comment above.