# How to develop/test/install packages in R in a isolated environment? Like an environment that behave like a brand-new R installation

Tags: r, testing, package, development-environment

Here is a example situation: I wish to test if a new user of my R package will be able to install. If it will demand any additional configuration that I have in my developer environment and the user do not have.

I would like to see possibilities. I have already tried **Docker** and **Virtual Machines**. But I guess that exists easier ways to accomplish this!

Edit:
What I want is possible to do in Virtual Machines/Docker!
I made a brand-new system to check what errors can I get when installing the package in this new environment.
What I really want here is to know how to do a new configuration of a new environment in my own PC, and not in a virtual machine like system.

Comment: Might it improve the question if you say what you have tried with Docker and Virtual Machines and if it was successful or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!require(somepackage)){
    install.packages("somepackage")
    library(somepackage)
}
```

Maybe this is some of your solution in the packages question

Link of the info:
[Elegant way to check for missing packages and install them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them)