# Check and force update packages

Tags: r

I'm working on a script to check and update packages if they're out of date. Below is what I've got so far, but on startup (click .Rproj which runs the script in my Rprofile) the session goes into an infinite loop. I was getting this warning:

```
Error in install.packages : cannot remove prior installation of package ‘haven’
```

So I remove.packages('haven') and deleted the folder in /R/library.

After running again in a new session, from the output it looks like it tries to redownload and install haven 4(!) times before finishing. Can anyone spot why or offer some tips about this workflow?

Last thing I'll add is that I've seen some other [very helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62809204/7448886) recommending `require()` which I will probably switch to using, but haven't gotten to yet.
Thanks!

```
### load needed packages 
# set up list of important packages 
# check if they're installed
# if not, install
# check if they're updated
# if not, update

#list of necessary packages 
listOfPackages <- c('tidyverse', #'tidyselect','readr','readxl','stringr','sjlabelled','forcats',
                    'lubridate',
                    'writexl',
                    'haven',
                    'janitor',
                    'glue',
                    'reshape2',
                    'skimr',
                    'codebook',
                    'labelled')

#loop to load packages, and install if not installed previously
# i <- 8

for (i in listOfPackages) {
  # set local CRAN mirror
  local({
    r <- getOption("repos")
    r["CRAN"] <- "https://cloud.r-project.org"
    options(repos = r)})
  
  if (!i %in% utils::installed.packages()) {
    # repos 1 chooses the cloud version "closest"
    utils::install.packages(i, 
                            dependencies = TRUE, 
                            repos = 1)
  }
  # if installed update
  else {
    # ask = false stops prompt for all updates
    utils::update.packages(oldPkgs = listOfPackages, 
                           ask = FALSE)
  }
}

## print a list of important packages installed
# filter to packages we want to know about
pkgs <- tibble::tibble(
  Package = names(utils::installed.packages()[, 3]),
  Version = unname(utils::installed.packages()[, 3])
)
# print the packages we care about and their versions
cat("These are the important libraries loaded and their versions.",
    "\n",
    "If you need to use a new package, please add it to the 'listofPackages in pkg_check.R",
    "\n")

print(pkgs[grep(paste0(listOfPackages, collapse = "|"),
                pkgs["Package"][[1]]), ])
```

Comment: I don't see that you ever load any packages. Installation and loading are different.  Loading needs either `library` or `require`.  They both load a package but `require` returns a logical value so that success can be programmatically checked.

Comment: ruh oh you're right. I can add a `for (i in listOfPackages){library(i, character.only = TRUE)}` at the end to do that!

Comment: You are also running `installed.packages` every time through that loop body which builds a list from file. Why not run it once, save the result, and then check for a matching value at that point in your logic.

Comment: good idea. Thanks!